# Get amount of passed and failed jenkins tests from another jenkins job with pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I start Jenkins job `job_name1` from my jenkins pipeline.

```
build job: 'job_name1', parameters: [ string(name: 'name1', value: 'value1') ], propagate: false
```

Job `job_name1` exected and it has 100 passed 10 failed test with JUnit.

How can I get amount of passed and failed tests?
I Did try with:

```
import hudson.model.Run
import hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
import hudson.model.Action

node("node_name")
{
   def my_build = build(job: 'job_name1', parameters: [ string(name: 'name1', value: 'value1') ], propagate: false,)
   defresults = (my_build as Run).getAction(TestResultAction) 
   def allTests = results.getResult()
   def failedTests = results.getFailCount()
}
```

and get following error

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@7c845e2' with class 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper' to class 'hudson.model.Run'
```

How can I do it? 
Is it possible to do this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`RunWrapper#getRawBuild`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getRawBuild--) to get actual [`Run`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html) object

```
defresults = my_build.rawBuild.getAction(TestResultAction)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I tried but I've got error `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)`

Comment: @nick_gabpe you have to approve [`RunWrapper#getRawBuild`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getRawBuild--)  as well as other methods you use. See more the detail in [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)